# Updating an ngIf when onSubmit is clicked

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

What is an easy way to convert the *ngif that display the image to be called by the onSubmit (button click) instead?

Currently when an item is chosen on the dropdown menu it triggers the *ngIF for the image. I want to change this so that the image will only change/update once onSubmit is selected.

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle col" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false">
      {{form.site}} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu col">
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="form.site='main2'">Main 2</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="form.site='main3'">Main 3</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="input-group field">
    <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit($event)" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-primary col">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <!-- image loading -->
  <div class="row" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <h5 *ngIf="form.site=='main2'">
      <img src="assets/img/small.png"> Today</h5>
    <h5 *ngIf="form.site=='main3'">
      <img src="assets/img/s_small.png"> Today</h5>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Chellappan i've added more details

Answer (score 1):

Change the click event on the drop down items to call a function in your typescript class. That function will set a variable and the *ngIf will be off of that variable.

Comment: can you give a rough example? i've changed `ng-click="formSite('main2')"` from `(click)="form.site='main2'"`

Comment: If I am understanding, you are saying that you changed the click event to "formSite('main2')", so now there should be a formSite(variableName: string) method within your typescript file that will set a variable (say displayImage) that can be used by your *ngIf on your images to determine which image to display.